# Shell script program - Filter rows from log file which having disk-space utilization size more than 80%

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, sh

I have one following log file (input-log-file.log) and i want to do filter on log file using shell script (.sh) which give me rows which having disk space utilization more than 80% (>= 80) along with server name in output file.

input-log-file.log :

```
====================== Server-1: user@x.xxx.xx.xx ======================
/data/file/test 50G 5.3G 45G 11% /opt/apps/user

====================== Server-2: user@xx.xxx.xx.xx ======================
/data/xyz/test 100G 30G 45G 86% /opt/apps/user

====================== Server-3: user@xx.xx.xx.xxx ======================
/dev/env/volume 5.0G 418M 4.6G 55% /opt/apps/user
/dev/env/volume 100G 59G 42G 59% /opt/apps/user
/dev/env/volume 200G 51G 150G 92% /opt/apps/user/abc1


====================== Server-4: user@xx.xx.xx.xxx ======================
/dev/env/flow_vol 100G 60G 41G 82% /opt/apps/user
/dev/env/flow_vol/data 100G 39G 62G 39% /opt/apps/user
/dev/env/flow_vol/data 100G 20G 81G 20% /opt/apps/user/xyz
/dev/env/flow_vol/test 200G 66G 135G 96% /opt/apps/user/
```

My excepted output in new file as below (i.e. output-log-file.log):

```
====================== Server-2: user@xx.xxx.xx.xx ======================
/data/xyz/test 100G 30G 45G 86% /opt/apps/user

====================== Server-3: user@xx.xx.xx.xxx ======================
/dev/env/volume 200G 51G 150G 92% /opt/apps/user/abc1

====================== Server-4: user@xx.xx.xx.xxx ======================
/dev/env/flow_vol 100G 60G 41G 82% /opt/apps/user
/dev/env/flow_vol/test 200G 66G 135G 96% /opt/apps/user/
```

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I written below shell script which give me rows which having disk space utilization more than 80% (>= 80) but I am NOT getting the server name.

disk-space-filter.sh file :

```
awk '{original_block=$0; FS=" "; gsub(/\(|\)|%/,"");  if($5>=80) print original_block }' input-log-file.log > output-log-file.log
```

If i run the above shell script my program (./disk-space-filter.sh) then I am able to get the below output in new file but not getting server name :

```
/data/xyz/test 100G 30G 45G 86% /opt/apps/user
/dev/env/volume 200G 51G 150G 92% /opt/apps/user/abc1
/dev/env/flow_vol 100G 60G 41G 82% /opt/apps/user
/dev/env/flow_vol/test 200G 66G 135G 96% /opt/apps/user/
```

Any help would be really appreciated?

Comment: is your question PowerShell related? If so, in what way?

Comment: See the [awk tutorial](https://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) and read about RS and ORS variables. You'll need to use `ORS="\n\n"`   (not mentioned in tutorial) to achieve your required output, but I highly recommend solution below, as now you have all important information on one line of text, and this would be easier to process in any downstream reports, processes.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'[ %]' -v n=80 '
    NF==4{
        head=$0
    }
    $5>=n && head{
        print head; head=""
    }
    $5>=n
' file

====================== Server-2: user@xx.xxx.xx.xx ======================
/data/xyz/test 100G 30G 45G 86% /opt/apps/user
====================== Server-3: user@xx.xx.xx.xxx ======================
/dev/env/volume 200G 51G 150G 92% /opt/apps/user/abc1
====================== Server-4: user@xx.xx.xx.xxx ======================
/dev/env/flow_vol 100G 60G 41G 82% /opt/apps/user
/dev/env/flow_vol/test 200G 66G 135G 96% /opt/apps/user/
```

Comment: Thanks @ufopilot for the answer,  Your logic is working fine except one condition, If input file having disk-space 9% then it is also printed in output file but we want only those rows which is having >=80%  

Could you please help me to fix this?

Comment: Thank you so much @ufopilot ... Your logic is working as per expected.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
awk '/^=/{server=$2}{sub(/%/,"", $5); if ($5>=80) print server, $0}' file
```

or multi-line:

```
awk '
    /^=/{server=$2}
    {sub(/%/,"", $5); if ($5>=80) print server, $0}
' file
```

```
Server-2: /data/xyz/test 100G 30G 45G 86 /opt/apps/user
Server-3: /dev/env/volume 200G 51G 150G 92 /opt/apps/user/abc1
Server-4: /dev/env/flow_vol 100G 60G 41G 82 /opt/apps/user
Server-4: /dev/env/flow_vol/test 200G 66G 135G 96 /opt/apps/user/
```

Comment: Thanks @Gilles Quénot for the answer,  Your logic is working fine except one condition, If input file having disk-space 9% then it is also printed in output file but we want only those rows which is having >=80%  

Could you please help me to fix this?